# How to correctly build with ant using drools?

Tags: java, ant, build, drools

I am trying to build drools with ant using DroolsCompilerAntTask but I keep running into errors. I was wondering if my setup is wrong or something that should be configured differently.

build.xml

```
...

    <taskdef name="droolscompiler" classpathref="java:buildtime.classpath" classname="org.drools.contrib.DroolsCompilerAntTask" />

    <path id="build.path">
        <pathelement location="${homedir}/build" />
    </path>

    <target name="verify-rules">
        <droolscompiler srcdir="${homedir}/src/rules" tofile="${homedir}/build/rules.pkg"
                binformat="package" classpathref="build.path">
            <include name="**/*.drl" />
        </droolscompiler>
    </target>
...
```

The error message I got was

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\John\workspace\project\tools\build.xml:55: 
RuleBaseTask failed: Unable to load dialect 'org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration:java:org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration'

Total time: 45 seconds
```

Update: I only want to compile the rules. I dont need to compile the java files.

Update: Drools versions -

```
                          drools-compiler-5.4.0.Final.jar
                          drools-core-5.4.0.Final-sources.jar
                          drools-core-5.4.0.Final.jar
                          drools-decisiontables-5.4.0.Final.jar
                          drools-jsr94-5.4.0.Final.jar
                          drools-spring-5.4.0.Final.jar
                          drools-templates-5.4.0.Final.jar
                          drools-ant-5.4.0.final.jar
```

Comment: To exclude problems not related to that ant task: Can you compile these .drl files without using ant, i.e., just by calling the Drools API? - And: always state the Drools version with questions on Drools.

Comment: yes. .drl files can be executed in run time. what I want is to pre-compile the rule files as part of the build so if rule has syntax error for example it will fail the build and not create error during runtime.

Comment: I know how to compile .drl. The question is whether the ones you have and want to compile with ant can be compiled using the API - no errors, no other problems.

Comment: yes i know how to compile drl it is just with ant i have the problem. After I exclude the path for the drool-compile.jar it works fine, but now the question is it does not read with the java class files.